# Alinear texto de items en un QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy tratando de centrar los textos de un item de una `QTableWidget` para lo cual ocupo lo siguiente:

```
self.tabla.insertRow(self.tabla.rowCount())
self.tabla.setItem(self.tabla.rowCount()-1,0,QTableWidgetItem(_id).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter))
```

pero no centra el texto, al contrario, al incluir la linea `.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)` el texto ni siquiera se muestra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se muestra nada porque a al argumento `item` de `QTableWidget.setItem` le pasas precisamente eso, nada. Al hacer:

```
QTableWidgetItem(_id).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
```

lo que haces es lo siguiente:

1. Creas un objeto `QTableWidgetItem` con `QTableWidgetItem(_id)`.
2. Lamas al método [`setTextAlignment`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setTextAlignment) del objeto recién creado, el cual asigna correctamente la alineación y retorna. **Este método retorna `None` y es ese retorno el que se le pasa a `QTableWidget.setItem`**, no una instancia de `QTableWidgetItem`.

Por lo tanto, lo que haces es básicamente:

```
self.tabla.setItem(self.tabla.rowCount() - 1, 0, None)
```

La solución es simple, instancia el objeto y asígnalo a una variable para mantener una referencia al mismo, luego usa dicha variable para llamar a su método `setTextAlignment` y para pasarlo finalmente a `QTableWidget.setItem`:

```
self.tabla.insertRow(self.tabla.rowCount())
item = QTableWidgetItem(_id)
item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
self.tabla.setItem(self.tabla.rowCount() - 1, 0, item)
```

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore



class Example(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget) 
        self.setLayout(self.layout) 

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)

        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(2):
                item = QTableWidgetItem("Item {}-{}".format(i, j))
                item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```